# EntityFramework Core loading related data with anonymous classes causes multiple subselects

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I recognized that when I query a list of objects with related data using Entity Framework Core in a .NET Core Web API it works fine as long as I do not try to use anonymous classes for hiding some fields.

When I use the anonymous classes the related data is loaded from the DB with one call for each entry. In the example below this means for each person a DB call is created to query the related details (according to log files).

Since the person list is long this means the DB is hammered by the queries which I try to avoid.

Simple situation with two tables:

```
Person (id, firstname, lastname, someOtherField)

PersonDetails (id, PersonId, DetailText, someOtherDetailField)
```

It works perfectly fine with one DB call if i pick all fields and use eager loading.

Given this code:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var result = _db.Media.Include(m => m.Thumbnail);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

results in output like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "First1",
    "lastname": "Last1",
    "groupAssignment": [],
    "personDetails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "personId": 1,
        "detailText": "details1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output I am looking for has only selected fields on Person and only selected fields on PersonDetails, like that:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "First1",
    "lastname": "Last1",
    "personDetails": [
      {
        "detailText": "details1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Currently I am at this state using an anoymous class for hiding the person fields:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var result = _dbContext.Person
                    .Include(p => p.PersonDetails)
                    .Select(
                        p => new
                        {
                            p.Firstname,
                            p.Lastname,
                            p.PersonDetails
                        }
                    );
    return Ok(result);
}
```

But this leaves me with two problems:

1. I causes an seperate database query for each Person to request the PersonDetails
2. For some reason I can not use

   ```
   p.PersonDetails.Select(d => new {d.DetailText})
   ```

   to filter the fields of the PersonDetails.

Any suggestions how I could query/return the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers of other questions I figured out there has been two problems

`.AsEnumerable()` makes EF to query the related data with one call (what does not mean the whole query is one call but at least all the related data is queried with one call)

`personDetails =` makes the anonymous data a named var which allows to select only specific fields.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var result = _dbContext.Person
        .Include(p => p.PersonDetails)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(
            p => new
            {
                p.Firstname,
                p.Lastname,
                personDetails = p.PersonDetails.Select(d => new {d.DetailsText} )
            }
        );
    return Ok(result);
}
```